# Django: Why won't the option render as selected?

Tags: html, django, django-templates

EDITED:

In my html template I have a select control and want to set the selected option based on a variable `{{specialtyId}}`.  The expected result is that the selected option will be selected, but the actual result is that no option is selected.

Just to make sure it wasn't just the `select` control that was affected, I also used a similar loop to generate labels with either "selected" or "not selected" based on the `if` statement test.

Here is the code:

```
<label>{{specialtyId}} was selected</label>
<br>
{% for s in specialties %}
    <label>{{s.specialtyId}} {{s.specialtyName}} {% if s.specialtyId == specialtyId %} selected {% else %} not selected {% endif %}</label><br>
{% endfor %}

<select class="form-control" id="specialtyId" name="specialtyId" required="True">
{% for s in specialties %}
    <option value="{{s.specialtyId}}" {% if s.specialtyId == specialtyId %} selected {% endif %}>{{s.specialtyName}}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

Here a screen shot of the actual selected value, the labels generated, and the dropdown generated.  Even though `specialtyId` is clearly 2 from the output `2 was selected` both the labels aren't "selected" and neither is the dropdown options[image].

So I've made the change as suggested in the upvoted answer below and restarted the browser and cleared the cache but still no success.

Comment: What is `value` here? Can you shere the `repr(..)` of the dictionary you pass to the rendering?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem the repr of the list of specialties is a list of SpecialtyListResult objects, each of which is simply an integer specialtyId and a character specialtyName

Answer (score 4):

You need to change:

```
{% if value == specialtyId %}
```

To:

```
{% if s.specialtyId == specialtyId %}
```

`Value` has nothing to do here.

*edit* : if this still not work, check that `s.specialtyId` and `specialtyId` can be compared (eg : string 2 is not equal to integer 2).

Comment: You restarted and refresh the html without cache?

Answer (score 0):

Although the answer by @Bestasttung was correct, it was not sufficient to solve the problem.  I tried this:

```
{% if s.specialtyId == 2 %}
```

Which immediately made the second, and only the second, option selected.  At that point I realized that somehow

```
{% if s.specialtyId == specialtyId %}
```

was never true, and it **turned out to be because of different data types**.  I changed my class contained in the dictionary to be of type `Charfield` instead of `IntegerField`

```
class SpecialtyListResult:
    specialtyId = models.CharField()
    specialtyName = models.CharField(max_length=40)
```

And then changed how it was filled by the database cursor, to be a string type:

```
for row in curs:
    slr = SpecialtyListResult()
    slr.specialtyId = str(row[0])
    slr.specialtyName = row[1]
    list_specialties.append(slr)
```

And it works now.